# Create a MS-Word Style that Indents Based On Parent Heading

Tags: ms-word

Is it possible in MS-Word to set a style's indent to be relative to the heading it falls under in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that isn't possible.
What you can do is define paragraph styles to use after each heading and set them as the "Style for following paragraph". That way the correct style will be applied after each heading.